# How to do a JOIN from two different columns to the same column on a separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two columns on one table that reference the same column on a second table in order to obtain the name that relates to an specified ID.

Below is the query that I am using that is not working.  The two LEFT JOINS on the invTypes causes the problem.  I have read and read and have been racking my brain on this.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this return the names that belong to the IDs that appear in two separate locations in the main table.

THings to note with out posting the entire database structure (which is huge)

both the `typeID` and `itemTypeID` are present on the main table.  Each of those references the same `typeID` column in the `invTypes`  table.  The `invTypes` table contains the name that corresponds to said ID.

Additionally, in the SELECT part of the statement, the `typeName` comes from the `invTypes` and the `stationName` comes from the `staStations` table.

The main question is, if the invTypes.`typeName` is referenced two times from two columns, how do i 1: properly join the tables to those two points and 2: how do i tell the difference in the two invTypes.`typeName` that is to be returned if the two JOIN statements can be made.

```
SELECT 
`logTime`,`itemID`,`typeName`,`actorName`,`stationName`,`action`,`passwordType`,
`quantity`,`oldConfiguration`,`newConfiguration` 
        FROM eve_container_audit 
        LEFT JOIN invTypes ON eve_container_audit.typeID = invTypes.typeID
        LEFT JOIN invTypes ON eve_container_audit.itemTypeID = invTypes.typeID

        LEFT JOIN staStations ON eve_container_audit.locationID = staStations.stationID
```

Comment: Some example data would help understand this better cause from the looks of it seems that the `typeID` and `itemTypeID` have the same value in each row of the eve_container_audit?

Comment: ok the itemTypeID references a container type and the typeID references the items that are inside the container, however, both of the id's get there name from the same location on another table.  I hope this helps.  It will be very difficult to give actual representations of the data as the tables are large and have a ton of usless stuff in relation to the question at hand.  As both the container and the items inside it are items just the same they get there name from the same item database in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to join them just once :

```
SELECT 
  `logTime`,
  `itemID`,
  `typeName`,
  `actorName`,
  `stationName`,
  `action`,
  `passwordType`,
  `quantity`,
  `oldConfiguration`,
  `newConfiguration` 
FROM
  eve_container_audit 
LEFT JOIN
  invTypes
ON
  eve_container_audit.typeID = invTypes.typeID and
  eve_container_audit.itemTypeID = invTypes.typeID
LEFT JOIN
  staStations
ON
  eve_container_audit.locationID = staStations.stationID
```

If you need to join them twice, use alias :

```
SELECT 
  `logTime`,
  `itemID`,
  `typeName`,
  `actorName`,
  `stationName`,
  `action`,
  `passwordType`,
  `quantity`,
  `oldConfiguration`,
  `newConfiguration` 
FROM
  eve_container_audit 
LEFT JOIN
  invTypes
ON
  eve_container_audit.typeID = invTypes.typeID
LEFT JOIN
  invTypes invTypes2
ON
  eve_container_audit.itemTypeID = invTypes2.typeID
LEFT JOIN
  staStations
ON
  eve_container_audit.locationID = staStations.stationID
```

Comment: The second query worked like a charm.  Thank you very much.  Your example will help me very much in the future in understanding how to use aliases which happens to be something that i struggle with quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Basically create a second alias of the same table. In the selects refer to inv1 or inv2 specifically to get the right values.

```
SELECT 
     `logTime`,`itemID`, inv1.`typeName` as main_type , inv2.`typeName` as sub_type, `actorName`,`stationName`,`action`,`passwordType`,
     `quantity`,`oldConfiguration`,`newConfiguration` 
FROM eve_container_audit 
      LEFT JOIN invTypes as inv1 ON eve_container_audit.typeID = inv1.typeID
      LEFT JOIN invTypes as inv2 ON eve_container_audit.itemTypeID = inv2.typeID
      LEFT JOIN staStations ON eve_container_audit.locationID = staStations.stationID
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inv2.`typeName` as sub_type, `actorName`,`stationName`,`action`,`passwordType`,
' at line 2

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  This also worked like a charm.  I have already marked one correct but i have +1ed ya. Thank you very much.  This answer will hopefully help me and others that search this site that are looking to understand how aliases work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are joining the same table twice, you need to give unique aliases to the two copies of the table, or your query will be ambiguous.

```
...
LEFT JOIN invTypes ON eve_container_audit.typeID = invTypes.typeID
LEFT JOIN invTypes ON eve_container_audit.itemTypeID = invTypes.typeID
...
```

should instead be something like

```
...
LEFT JOIN invTypes AS invtypes1 ON
    eve_container_audit.typeID = invtypes1.typeID
LEFT JOIN invTypes AS invtypes2 ON
    eve_container_audit.itemTypeID = invtypes2.typeID
...
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'invTypes.typeID' in 'on clause' I do not know why it is saying unknown column because it does exist.

Comment: Edited. I had forgotten to change `invTypes` to `invtypes1`.