# Join Tables with One Common Column Per Pair

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

Good Morning,

I was given an order to amalgamate a report in excel with info that I extract from SQL Server DB. I have these tables which I need to join, as follows:

Department

```
DID           DName
1            Finance
2            Engineering
3            Administration
```

User

```
UID            UName           RID
1           Takamiya Aido      5
2           Yagari Touga       4
3           Kain Akatsuki      3
4           Kuran Kaname       2
5           Kiryuu Zero        1
```

Role

```
RID        RName
1         Executive Secretary
2         Maintenance Supervisor
3         Boilermaker
4         Fitter
5         Payroll Clerk
```

MetaData

```
MID      RID         Value
1         3        Engineering
2         2        Engineering
3         4        Engineering
4         5        Finance
5         1        Administration
```

CostCenters

```
CID      Code       Description
1        154      Administration
2        263      Mobiles
3        363      Services
4        554      General Accounts
5        654      Payroll Processing
```

DeptCost

```
ID      DID     CID
1       1        5
2       2        2
3       2        3
4       3        1
5       3        4
```

The code I use is the following:

```
SELECT D.DName, U.UName, R.RName, C.Code, C.Description
FROM Department D
INNER JOIN MetaData MD ON D.DptName = MD.Value
INNER JOIN User U ON MD.RoleID = U.RoleID
INNER JOIN Role R ON U.RoleID = R.RID
FULL JOIN DeptCost DC ON D.DeptID = DC.DeptId
FULL JOIN Cost C ON DC.CostId = C.CId
ORDER BY MD.Value
```

The expected result is this:

```
Dname             UName           RName               Code      Description
Finance          Takamiya Aido     Payroll Clerk       654     Payroll Proc
Engineering      Yagari Touga      Fitter              263     Mobiles
Engineering      Kain Akatsuki     Boilermaker         363     Services
Engineering      Kuran Kaname      Maintenance Sup
Administration   Kiryuu Zero       Executive Secretary 154  Administration
Administration                                         554  General Accounts
```

The actual result is this:

```
Dname             UName           RName               Code      Description
Finance          Takamiya Aido     Payroll Clerk       654     Payroll Proc
Engineering      Yagari Touga      Fitter              263     Mobiles
Engineering      Yagari Touga      Fitter              363     Services
Engineering      Kain Akatsuki     Boilermaker         263     Mobiles
Engineering      Kain Akatsuki     Boilermaker         363     Services
Engineering      Kuran Kaname      Maintenance Sup     263     Mobiles
Engineering      Kuran Kaname      Maintenance Sup     363     Services
Administration   Kiryuu Zero       Executive Secretary 154  Administration
Administration   Kiryuu Zero       Executive Secretary 554  General Accounts
```

I have tried the solutions in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491802/how-do-i-join-two-tables-with-different-column-in-sql-server-ce), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920802/how-to-do-a-join-from-two-different-columns-to-the-same-column-on-a-separate-tab), [Here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/advanced-pivottables-combining-data-from-multiple-sheets--cms-21190) as well as Google. I can get Dept and Users, Dept and Costs, but I can't do the three of them. To get the Users in Department, I have to get the Departments from the MetaData able, join it with Role and from Role get the User table. Depts and Cost Centers are straight forward as you can see.

I have tried other options deriving from the examples in here but not getting the expected result. If you say only CTEs or Partitions are the solution, please let them be the solutions because I have tried and I can't get a clear explanation on how they work, might be simple to some but I'm unable to grasp it. Don't know how I am going to get my MCSE without it.

If this will not work in SQL and only Excel itself is the solution, I will direct myself there. Short of faking the data manually and then making up a random excuse to my boss as to why it doesn't update automatically, I don't get this.

Any further explanation, just ask. Oh, can't touch the DB structure, and certain pieces of data were omitted because of confidentiality.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The boss wants a list of all users by department, and he wants the cost centers for each department. I created the report in Excel with 2 worksheets, one for Users and another for cost centers, however he asked to have it all together on the same sheet.

So, you may have departments with only 1 cost center but 5 employees, or you may have department with 5 cost centers and 3 employees. Actually, users and cost centers only have department in common, not related in themselves.

This is the fiddle as requested.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/477d9/1

Comment: You have **two** `DeptCost`s for some departments and have provided no way for the system to know which **one** you prefer. How can it know that, for some cost centre rows, you want to blank out certain `user` columns? You'll need to tell it. However, that seems like a job for a frontend, to blank out based on the previous row - not really the database engine, which is doing exactly what it should. Some SQL dialects do have commands for that sort of thing, but I'm not sure if 2008 R2 does.

Comment: Try using http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create tables and data with your query and post the fiddle here. That will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this clause right before the `ORDER BY` in your query:

```
GROUP BY D.DName, U.UName, R.RName
```

And then write either aggregate functions or subqueries that will enforce the rules you want for calculating `Code` and `Description`.

It is not clear from your question what those rules are.   For example, for `Yagari Touga` why do you want `Mobiles` and not `Services` in your final results?   I can't tell you how to code the logic if you don't tell us what the logic is.